# Unable to navigate to specific UIViewController when handling local notification action (when app is in background)

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to achieve a flow of a user receiving a local notification, responding with a specific action when then takes them to a specific view controller (not the root).

My understanding is that I need to push to the rootViewController, and from there push to the desired destinationViewController.

Here's what I've tried with the most success in the AppDelegate notification handler:

```
//  self.window?.rootViewController = root
//  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DestinationViewController") as! DestinationViewController
self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```

The 'popToViewController' line does nothing. In fact the only time anything happened was when I uncomment the two commented lines, but as soon as I make a ViewController the root and make it visible, it looses its connection to the NavigationController. This makes me thing that the NavigationController is the actual root, but I am unable to set it as the rootViewController.

I should add that I have created the NavigationController in Storyboard. Should I create it programatically instead?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I'm also busy trying this which feels like it might be more along the right path, but still no success:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

var rootVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardVC") as! DashboardVC
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
self.window?.rootViewController = nav

let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DestinationViewController") as! DestinationViewController 
nav.popToViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure if this is the best way about it, but it works for if the app is running in the background as well as if its closed:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var root = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardVC") as! DashboardVC
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: root)

self.window?.rootViewController = nav

root.performSegueWithIdentifier("destinationSegue", sender: self)
```

I went the performSegueWithIdentifier route because none of the 'popToViewController' methods did anything.

Comment: where these line should be written?